# how to create a hashtable dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, hashtable

I have a web application which will return JSON as response and its response is something like following :

```
{"album1" : "track1" , "album1" : "track2" , "album1" : "track3" , "album2" : "track1"}
```

please note the architecture of back end is out of my hand and I'm not able to change the way it create json (repeated key)

so I want to create a hashtable in javascript the idea of my hashtable should be  something like :

```
"album1" : ["track1" , "track2" , "track3"]
```

my question is how can I create such behavior in javascript?

I know how to create hashmap but not hashtable.

Comment: Your JSON has multiple keys called `"album1"`. JavaScript interpreter will (probably) overwrite keys. The JSON you posted becomes `{"album1":"track3","album2":"track1"}`.

Comment: The best thing you can do is tell your back-end guys to do their work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Well if this structure remains intact, you could probably hack together a function which does it. Something on the lines as below

```
var response = '{"album1" : "track1" , "album1" : "track2" , "album1" : "track3" , "album2" : "track1"}'
.replace(/}?{?/g, '');

var sanitisedData = {};

var transform = response.split(',').map(function(item){
    return JSON.parse('{' + item + '}');
}).forEach(function(item){
    var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
    if(!sanitisedData [key]) sanitisedData [key] = [];
    sanitisedData [key].push(item[key]);
});

//output - {"album1":["track1","track2","track3"],"album2":["track1"]}
```